# Filter context for should in bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

Elasticsearch documentation says

> If the bool query is a filter context or has neither must or filter then at least one of the should queries must match a document for it to match the bool query.

So I can have a bool query with a should clause along with must or filter within a filter context and then still get an exact match. How to do this combination?

I would also be interested in knowing how to do this with Jest client?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to add `minimum_should_match: 1` if you want that at least one of your should clauses match.